# mysteriously changing structure members (pointers involved):

Tags: c, pointers, random, memory-leaks, structure

Ok so I'll start this off by saying I'm quite new to programming, never mind this forum, and so if there's any more/less information I should give just let me know.  I hope I'm not asking a stupid question :P

Anyways, I'm attempting to write my first all-my-own-work program (well except for a simple 2d array program that serves as a multiplication program).  In it I'm essentially trying to make a simple model of game theory.  You have 2 people that can make a choice, which is predetermined and I denote as "int trait" which is 0 or 1. However I scale this up to having 100 people initially, and select 2 people at a time to randomly test, and depending on their traits, they're allotted different scores to determine how many "offspring" they'll have to conduct further tests, but that doesn't entirely matter because my issue is before then.

I set up my test subjects by making a struct:

```
struct Person { //used for testing and reproduction initialization
    int trait; // 0 for normal - 1 for phycopath
    int score; // reproductive score
    } ;
struct Person *id;
```

and then allocate memory like so:
`id = (struct Person *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct Person));`

and initialize the struct doing:

```
for(i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
    id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].trait = 0;
    id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score = 0;
}

for(i = nn; i < n; i++) {
    id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].trait = 1;
    id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score = 0; }
```

and before you say I'm doing everything wrong (and I'm not saying that I'm not), just some food for thought, I check that it initializes properly immediately afterwards using:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("id[%d].trait = %d\t", i, id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].trait);
        printf("id[%d].score = %d\n", i, id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score);
    }
```

Now my problem is that somewhere in my code (and I've done a few tests to point out to me about where the issue is), the traits in the test subjects are consistently altered for when i is between and including 26 and 37 (yes every time).  This suggests to me that somewhere in the code my variable id[] is being toyed with, yet i don't recall it at all between it's initialization and testing. And my tests have shown that the issue lies within:

```
for(i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
        if(p > 0) {
        srand( time(NULL) );
        randn = rand() % p; //MAKE SURE THIS IS OK
        storea = randn;
        storeaa = randf[randn];
        testa = storeaa * sizeof(struct Person);
```

testa (and also testb later on in the program) are used for recalling the test subjects in the exact same fashion that the above testing-print statement is done.

The program compiles and runs (just not the way I want it to), and about every ten times I try running it I get an error:

> Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) *
>   2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size ==
>   0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned
>   long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *
>   (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) &&
>   ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)'
>   failed.

which suggests to me that the random number generator could be the fault? Or a memory leak-some where? I'm really clueless at this point to be honest.

I'm sorry for the drawn out, and hopefully not too confusing explanation.  I've been working at this problem for a good 2 days and spent many hours researching online to avoid pestering people with my question.  Any ideas of what's going wrong would be greatly appreciated.  And for the completion of this question I'll post the entirety of my very sloppy code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Person { //used for testing and reproduction initialization
    int trait; // 0 for normal - 1 for phycopath
    int score; // reproductive score
    } ;
struct Person *id;
int n; // number of individuals


struct Person *temp;

//remember to type functions before main!!!
int main () {
    //beginning of initialization
    int n = 100; // number of members MUST BE EVEN!!!!!!
    int nn = (n / 2);
    printf("n = %d\nnn = %d\n", n, nn); 
    if(n == 100) { printf("n set to %d \n", n); }
    id = (struct Person *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct Person));//allocate memory for id
    temp = (struct Person *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(id != NULL);
    assert(temp != NULL);   
    int i = 0;
    int testa;
    int testb; //two subjects to be used for test
    //initialize rand-function array
    int p = n; //used for decrementing array and random size
    int *randf;
    int *randt;
    int randn;
    int t;
    int r;
    int kids;
    int offs;
    int tests = 0;
    int testkids = 0;
    int storea;
    int storeaa;
    int storeb;
    int storebb;
    int size = sizeof(struct Person);
    randf = malloc( n * sizeof(int));
    randt = malloc( p * sizeof(int));
    randf = realloc(randf, n * sizeof(int)); //allocation to randf
    assert(randf != NULL);
    assert(randt != NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
        printf("initialization of non-traits begun\n");
        id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].trait = 0;
        id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score = 0;
        printf("Person %d set\n", i);
    }

    for(i = nn; i < n; i++) {
        printf("initialization of with-traits begun\n");
        id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].trait = 1;
        id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score = 0;
        printf("Person %d set\n", i);
    } //initialization complete
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("id[%d].trait = %d\t", i, id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].trait);
        printf("id[%d].score = %d\n", i, id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score);
    }
    //beginning of test
    i = 0;


    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        randf[i] = i;
    }
    //selection and usage of test subjects
    i = 0;
    t = 0;
    r = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
        if(p > 0) {
        srand( time(NULL) );
        randn = rand() % p; //MAKE SURE THIS IS OK
        storea = randn;
        storeaa = randf[randn];
        testa = storeaa * size;
        //printf("%d\n", id[testa].trait);
        p = p - 1;
        randt = realloc(randt, p * sizeof(int));
        assert(randt != NULL);
        for(t = 0, r = 0; t < p; t++) { //copy randf over to randt exluding t = randn
            if(t != randn) {
                randt[r] = randf[t];
                r++;
            }
            else {}
        }
        randf = realloc(randf, p * sizeof(int));
        assert(randf != NULL);  
//              randf = randt;//copy randt back over to randf               
                for (t=0; t<p; t++) {
                   randf[t] = randt[t]; }
        srand( time(NULL) );
        randn = rand() % p; //MAKE SURE THIS IS RIGHT
        storeb = randn;
        storebb = randf[randn];
        testb = storebb * size;
        //printf("%d\n", id[testb].trait);
        p = p - 1;
        if( p > 0 ) { 
        randt = realloc(randt, p * sizeof(int));
        assert(randt != NULL);
            for(t = 0, r = 0; t < p; t++) { //same as before
                if(t != randn) {
                    randt[r] = randf[t];
                    r++;
                }
                else{}  
            }
            randf = realloc(randf, p * sizeof(int));
            assert(randf != NULL);
            for (t=0; t<p; t++) {
                       randf[t] = randt[t]; }
        }
        }       
        tests++;
    //TESTING TIME!!!
        if(id[testa].trait == 0 && id[testb].trait == 0) {
            id[testa].score = id[testa].score + 2;
            id[testb].score = id[testb].score + 2;
            //printf("Test Successful %d\n", tests);
        } else if(id[testa].trait == 0 && id[testb].trait == 1) {
            id[testa].score = id[testa].score + 1;
            id[testb].score = id[testb].score + 3;
            //printf("Test Successful %d\n", tests);
        } else if(id[testa].trait == 1 && id[testb].trait == 0) {
            id[testa].score = id[testa].score + 3;
            id[testb].score = id[testb].score + 1;
            //printf("Test Successful %d\n", tests);
        } else if(id[testa].trait == 1 && id[testb].trait == 1) {
            //printf("Test Successful %d\n", tests);
            // NO CHANGE
        }else {
            printf("ERROR: Test %d\n", tests);
            printf("id[testa].trait = %d\t%d,%d\n", id[testa].trait, storea, storeaa);
            printf("id[testb].trait = %d\t%d,%d\n", id[testb].trait, storeb, storebb);
        }

    } //END OF TESTING
//Commence Reproduction
    for(i = 0, kids = 0; i < n; i++) {
        kids = kids + id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score;
        testkids ++;
        //printf("%d kids calculated\n %d parents completed\n", kids, testkids);
    }
    temp = realloc(temp, kids * sizeof(struct Person));//REMEMBER TO FREE
    assert(temp != NULL);   
    r = 0;  
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(offs = id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score; offs > 0; offs--) {
            temp[r * sizeof(struct Person)].trait = id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].trait;
            temp[r * sizeof(struct Person)].score = 0;
            r++;
        }
    }
    n = kids;
    id = realloc(id, kids * sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(id != NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].trait = temp[i * sizeof(struct Person)].trait;
    id[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score = temp[i * sizeof(struct Person)].score;
    }
    printf("Done!");
    free(randf);
    free(randt);
    free(temp);
    free(id);   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler knows what id is a pointer to, so get rid of the sizeof from your id[] array indexing. It references the person at index n*sizeof(person) the way you have written it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of

> id[i * sizeof(struct Person)]

does not make sense.

It ought to be

```
id[i]
```

Comment: In that case should I go id = (struct Person *) malloc(n)
as opposed to id = (struct Person *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct Person))
and I also don't understand why my print statement to check if it initialized correctly works then?

Comment: No. While allocating memory using malloc, you have to provide the size which is `n * sizeof(struct Person)`. malloc does not know what type of data is going to be stored in the memory. But when you are using the variable `id` which is of type `Person *`, you have to index it as `[i]`. The compiler knows the size of `Person` and accesses the next Person in the array.. In short, only in the malloc statement you must use n*sizeof(...). The rest of the places will not need the sizeof statement.

Comment: Ok this does work, and I should've been less stubborn and tried it before, though i still don't understand why the initial print statement works

Comment: The reason it works is because you are using the same indices while assigning and printing. The problem is that the memory locations you are accessing are not those allocated by the malloc statements.